# Shortcut in R Studio to Change File Type

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a shortcut in RStudio to change file type? I know that ctrl + shift + n opens a new R script file, but I'm wondering if there is a quick shortcut to go from that to markdown without clicking the selector at the bottom right.

Comment: I do not believe so.

Comment: The closest I could find to this is: in `Tools -> Modify Keyboard Shortcuts`, you can set a keyboard shortcut to create a new *R Notebook* -- filter for the keyword "Notebook" and look for `New R Notebook`. This which will be (or perhaps can be set to) Markdown by default -- but if what you want is a blank .rmd file, this isn't quite that.